# Simple load testing script in bash

Tags: bash, timer, curl

Here's the code

```
max="$1"
date
echo "url: $2
rate: $max calls / second"
START=$(date +%s);

get () {
  curl -s -v "$1" 2>&1 | tr '\r\n' '\\n' | awk -v date="$(date +'%r')" '{print $0"\n-----", date}' >> /tmp/perf-test.log
}

while true
do
  echo $(($(date +%s) - START)) | awk '{print int($1/60)":"int($1%60)}'
  sleep 1

  for i in `seq 1 $max`
  do
    get $2 &
  done
done
```

This can be run as

`sh load-test.sh 20 "http://api.myserver.com/get_info"`

Please suggest if you think there's a way to take in multiple `curl` options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Arithmetics in Bash

You're doing some math in Bash, some in Awk, some in a combination of both. You can do all of that in Bash alone. Most notably, instead of this:

> ```
> echo $(($(date +%s) - START)) | awk '{print int($1/60)":"int($1%60)}'
> ```

This would be equivalent, but all in Bash, without additional processes:

```
((delta = $(date +%s) - START))
((minutes = delta / 60))
((seconds = delta % 60))
echo $minutes:$seconds
```

#### Don't use `seq`

`seq` is not portable, I suggest to avoid it. Instead of this:

> ```
>  for i in `seq 1 $max`; do ...; done
> ```

You can write:

```
for ((i = 1; i < max; i++)); do ...; done
```

#### Don't use `` `...` ``

This syntax is obsolete today, always use `$(...)` instead.

#### Other minor things

This would be clearer as two `echo` lines, or a here-document with `cat <<EOF`:

> ```
> echo "url: $2
> rate: $max calls / second"
> ```

The trailing semicolon is unnecessary:

> ```
> START=$(date +%s);
> ```

The quoting is unnecessary in `date +'%r'`, but it does no harm.

Comment: `seq` is very common in Linux these days.

Comment: I prefer my scripts to run everywhere

Comment: Every comment you made is valid, I over-looked them. Any word on the loooong `curl` command. It itches me but i couldn't do much.

Comment: @bigΩmega well, I'm wondering if you need the `tr` at all. I think you can simply drop that from the pipeline but I'm not sure. You can give that a try.

Comment: @janos So without that `tr` i only get the first line out of the pipe

Comment: @bigΩmega Interesting, and I don't understand why it behaves like that :-/